# Conflict Bison parser

Tags: c, compiler-construction, bison, lex

I'm new to Bison and I'm having trouble with shift/reduce conflicts...

I'm writing the rules for grammar for the C language: ID is a token that identifies a variable, and I wrote this rule to ensure that the identifier can be considered even if it is written in parentheses.

```
id              : '(' ID ')'    {printf("(ID) %s\n", $2);}
                |     ID        {printf("ID %s\n", $1);}
                ;
```

Output of Bison conflicts is:

```
State 82

   12 id: '(' ID . ')'
   13   | ID .

    ')'  shift, and go to state 22

    ')'       [reduce using rule 13 (id)]
    $default  reduce using rule 13 (id)
```

How can I resolve this conflict?

I hope I was clear and thanks for your help.

Comment: Is that the whole bison output? Also, can you provide it in English?

Comment: correct in english

Comment: Even for grammars, we need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](/help/mcve).

Comment: ... did you just translate that manually instead of rerunning bison in English?

Comment: yes, i have italian version but it's correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `id` rule in itself cannot cause a shift/reduce error. There must be some other rule in your grammar that uses `ID`. For example, you have an expression rule such as:

```
expr: '(' expr ')'
    | ID
    ;
```

In the above example, `ID` can reduce to `id` or to `expr` and the parser doesn't know which reduction to take. Check what is in state 22.

---

Edit: you ask "*what can I do to solve the conflict?*"

> I'm writing the rules for grammar for the C language: ID is a token that identifies a variable, and I wrote this rule to ensure that the identifier can be considered even if it is written in parentheses

A variable in parenthesis as a left-hand side is invalid in C, so it can only occur in a right-hand side. Then you can consider it an expression, so just remove your rule and where you use `id` replace that with `expr`.

Comment: You're right.
I have a rule of that type and if I comment it, I have no more conflict.
at this point how can I do?

Comment: See edit of my solution. If it helps you, then please click on the zero between the up/down arrows on the left to accept the solution.

Comment: Your answer is the best.
In C, however, grammatically speaking is allowed to do    (A) = (b)     given that the compilation have not errors.
But I shall adopt your solution. thank you